# How to copy an existing google form filled survey (with answers) to a new google form survey (to create a different link than the original survey)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am using google forms to survey the same patient each month.

Is there a way for me to create a different link to the patient's previous survey (and maintaining his/her answers) or to quickly copy and paste his/her answers into a different survey (to obtain a different link to the previous google forms survey, that I can paste and save?).

This would save me a lot of time lost filling out a new survey with the patient's past answers, every month that I have to contact the patient.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [prefilled](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839588?hl=en&ref_topic=9055305#zippy=%2Csend-a-form-with-pre-filled-answers) link. To automatically create prefilled links, use a formula in the form response destination spreadsheet to insert the data in a patient's existing response into a link template.

To get a link template, follow the instructions in the [help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839588?hl=en&ref_topic=9055305#zippy=%2Csend-a-form-with-pre-filled-answers). Use the text string concatenation operator `&` or functions like `substitute()` and `regexreplace()` to implement the formula.

Comment: Thanks so much Ruben! Do you know if it is possible to obtain different links instead of a single link out of a prefilled form, so I can use a different link each month?

Comment: In the form response destination spreadsheet, use a formula to insert the data in a patient's existing response into a link template. If you cannot write a formula to do that, post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and show what the form response destination sheet look like.